# Is there any string length limit in GoLang's string map key?

Tags: string, go, hashtable

Is there any maximum length of Go's string map key?
Actually I use https://github.com/OneOfOne/cmap instead of Go's map.

The question is, the key I use in that `cmap` is about 200-4000 characters in length, will it be a problem/gotchas?

```
import "github.com/kokizzu/gotro/I"
import "sync/atomic"

var CACHE_IDX int64
var CACHE_KEYS cmap.CMap

func init() {
    CACHE_KEYS = cmap.New()
}

// change a really long string to a shorter one 
func RamKey_ByQuery(query string) string {
    nkey := CACHE_KEYS.Get(query)
    if nkey != nil {
        return nkey.(string)
    }
    new_idx := atomic.AddInt64(&CACHE_IDX, 1)
    ram_key := `:` + I.ToS(new_idx) // convert integer to string
    CACHE_KEYS.Set(query, ram_key)
    return ram_key
}
```

Comment: Is your question about Go's builtin map type or about cmap? For Go: Read the spec. If there is no limit on map key length (there isn't) then there is no limit. For cmap: Why not ask the author?

Comment: Btw: There are several gotchas in your code but non is related to map-key lengths.

Comment: because internally cmap uses map

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the only limit is your memory.

Answer (score 5):

According to the go document, `len()` function has to be compatible with `string` which is returning `int`. The int type is usually 32 bits wide on 32-bit systems and 64 bits wide on 64-bit systems.

So, the range for signed `int` is `-2^(n -1) ~ 2^(n-1) -1`. Since length can't be negative, it should be `0 ~ 2^(n-1) -1`

Ref - https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len

Comment: So for a 64 bit system, I suppose a string could be math.MaxInt64 characters long, which is 9223372036854775807 on my PC. Out of curiosity, I found this in Quora: a typical hardcover book with 250 pages has about 500k characters including spaces.